# How to enable svg preview in file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, svg, preview

I want to preview .svg files in file explorer. I've been trying to use the file explorer extension available [here in github](https://github.com/maphew/svg-explorer-extension/releases), but to no avail. My Windows version is Windows 10 Home (more specifically, update 1809). My computer is x64 system, so I used that version. After installing the extension, I changed the default app, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/342052/how-to-get-svg-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer) but nothing changed.

I got curious and changed view setting in file explorer and found that when the view is set to Small icons/List/Details, I cannot preview the svg files(icon becomes whatever the default app is), but in other modes, like tiles, I can view the previews. Additionally, I have found that regardless of the view mode, preview in the Details pane(panel at the right edge of the file explorer) works. I have rebooted my pc and restarted explorer through task manager countless times. I also tried to remove the file association for .svg files entirely, hoping that would stop the icons from becoming the default app's. However, The default app just switched to internet explorer and I was not able to fully remove the file association.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: “but in other modes, like tiles, I can view the previews.” - Sounds like an incompatibility with the extension and Windows 10 1809 and/or a bug in the extension itself.  Have you reported the issue to the developer?

Comment: I have not reported the issue to the developer. Will do, though.