# Why SVG viewer extension fails to show preview of SVG files in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, svg

After following the answer on **[How to get SVG thumbnails in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/342052/how-to-get-svg-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer)**, there are still problems which hinders the preview of the SVG icons in Windows Explorer. Is there any solution to make it work correctly?

[image: Screenshot of icon problem]

Comment: Have you installed the right 32/64-bit extension (in doubt install both)? Which program do you use to open your SVG files?

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for your reply. I installed the 64-bit version. I use Adobe Illustrator to open SVG files.

Comment: Try to [reset the icon cache database](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-icon-cache-database-windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

Same case by here. I uninstalled it lot of times, both Git and original versions. Last thing I did was restart Windows 10. After booting, I tried to install the original version again (I remember clearly it was the v0.1.1), and it worked perfectly, without needing to refresh or set a default viewer! Well, that is all. Hope this can give you a hand.